# Can you change a pointer in loop?

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say I have a vector of integers:

```
vector<int> v(n);
```

Which I fill up in a for loop with valid values. What I want to do is to find a index of a given value in this vector. For example if I have a vector of `1, 2, 3, 4` and a value of 2, i'd get a index = 1. The algorithm would assume that the vector is sorted in ascending order, it would check a middle number and then depending of it's value (if its bigger or smaller than the one we're asking for) it would check one of halves of the vector. I was asked to do this **recursive** and using **pointer**. So I wrote a void function like:

```
void findGiven(vector<int> &v){
    int i = 0;
    int *wsk = &v[i];
}
```

and I can easily access 0th element of the vector. However I seem to have some basic knowledge lacks, because I can't really put this in a for loop to print all the values. I wanted to do something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j<v.size(); j++){
   cout << *wsk[j];
}
```

Is there a way of doing such a thing? Also I know it's recurisve, I'm just trying to figure out how to use pointers properly and how to prepare the algorithm so that later I can build it recursively. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you've trying to implement is called binary search. What you've implemented is nothing close to binary search.

Comment: Since `wsk` is an `int*`, `wsk[j]` is an `int`, and you can't dereference an `int`.

Comment: You're confusing index and pointer.

Comment: The question isn't about index or binary search itself, it's about what and how can I do with pointers and what I can not

Comment: You probably then should have not talked about that detail in your question and just focused on the pointer issue.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is:

```
for (int wsk : v) {
    cout << wsk;
}
```

If you insist on pointers:

```
int* first = v.data();
for (size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {
  cout << first[j];
}
```